# Timer called twice in scene Corona SDK

Tags: timer, lua, sdk, coronasdk, scene

I have a timer in my code that spawns objects every 1 seconds.
When an object collides with "deathObj" the scene changes from the scene2 to the scene1.
But when from the scene1 I return to the scene2 the timer is called twice, if I retry will be called 4 times etc...
How can I call the timer once?

```
function scene:show( event )

local sceneGroup = self.view
local phase = event.phase

if ( phase == "will" ) then

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        local function spawn()
            --things for spawn the object
        end

    end


    local function deathObjCollision(self, event)
        if (event.phase == "began" ) then
        composer.gotoScene("scene1")
        end
    end

    deathObj = display.newRect(300,1900,1600,100)
    physics.addBody(deathObj, "static", {density=1.0, friction=0.5, bounce=0.3})
    deathObj.collision = deathObjCollision
    deathObj:addEventListener( "collision", deathObj )


    spawnTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, spawn, -1)

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pause or cancel the timer when you change from scene 2 to scene 1.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this when the game finish the second time.

```
timer.cancel(spawnTimer)
spawnTimer = timer.performWithDelay(seconds, spawn, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tracing your code, you seem to have too many ends. It's really important to get your code indention correct for your own sanity as well as helping those who want to help you.

If I read your code right, your timer is outside of the "if - then - else" statement that tests if you're in the "will" phase or the "did" phase. The scene:show() event triggers twice, once off screen ("will") and once after it's on screen ("did"). Since your timer is outside of that if, it will execute twice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what you are saying is right but the problem was in another scene. In the scene1 there were two touch event listeners for the button that will bring you in the scene2, now I have fixed it.